# I created a custom Module, but table is not created, i also checked in core_resource, it's not there

Tags: magento-1.9, database, table

Here is the code

config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Bms_Calls>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Bms_Calls>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <calls>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Bms_Calls</module>
                    <frontName>calls</frontName>
                </args>
            </calls>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <calls>
                    <file>calls.xml</file>
                </calls>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <calls>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Bms_Calls</module>
                    <frontName>calls</frontName>
                </args>
            </calls>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <calls module="calls">
                <title>Call Enquiry</title>
                <sort_order>72</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <items module="calls">
                        <title>Calls List</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>calls/adminhtml_calls</action>
                    </items>
                </children>
            </calls>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <Bms_Calls>
                            <title>Calls Module</title>
                            <sort_order>12</sort_order>
                        </Bms_Calls>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <calls>
                    <file>calls.xml</file>
                </calls>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
    <global>
        <models>
            <calls>
                <class>Bms_Calls_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>calls_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </calls>
            <calls_mysql4>
                <class>Bms_Calls_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <calls>
                        <table>calls_enquiry</table>
                    </calls>
                </entities>
            </calls_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <calls_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Bms_Calls</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </calls_setup>
            <calls_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </calls_write>
            <calls_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </calls_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <calls>
                <class>Bms_Calls_Block</class>
            </calls>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <calls>
                <class>Bms_Calls_Helper</class>
            </calls>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

mysql script

```
<?php

$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("

-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('calls_enquiry')};
CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('calls_enquiry')} (
  `calls_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(150) NOT NULL default '',
  `phone` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `message` text NOT NULL default '',
  `status` smallint(6) NOT NULL default '0',
  `leadowner` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `feedback` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `created_time` datetime NULL,
  `update_time` datetime NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`calls_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    ");

$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: No time to check, but please do not use deprecated Mysql4 classes ... and split config and acl (system) into differnt xml ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have this file

> app/etc/modules/Bms_Calls.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Bms_Calls>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Bms_Calls>
  </modules>
</config>
```

I have also checked your xml, it looks fine

Try to replace your `config.xml` with this (Backup your current config.xml file first)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Bms_Calls>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Bms_Calls>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <calls>
        <use>standard</use>
          <args>
            <module>Bms_Calls</module>
            <frontName>calls</frontName>
          </args>
      </calls>
    </routers>
        <layout>
          <updates>
            <calls>
              <file>calls.xml</file>
            </calls>
          </updates>
        </layout>
  </frontend>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <calls>
        <class>Bms_Calls_Helper</class>
      </calls>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <calls>
        <class>Bms_Calls_Block</class>
      </calls>
    </blocks>
    <resources>
      <calls_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>Bms_Calls</module>
        </setup>
        <connection>
          <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
      </calls_setup>
      <calls_write>
        <connection>
          <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
      </calls_write>
      <calls_read>
        <connection>
          <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
      </calls_read>
    </resources>
  </global>
  <admin>
    <routers>
      <calls>
        <use>admin</use>
        <args>
          <module>Bms_Calls</module>
          <frontName>admin_calls</frontName>
        </args>
      </calls>
    </routers>
  </admin>
  <adminhtml>
    <menu>
      <calls module="calls">
        <title>Calls</title>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        <children>
          <callsbackend module="calls">
            <title>Backend Page Title</title>
            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
            <action>admin_calls/adminhtml_callsbackend</action>
          </callsbackend>
        </children>
      </calls>
    </menu>
    <acl>
      <resources>
        <all>
          <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
          <children>
            <calls translate="title" module="calls">
              <title>Calls</title>
              <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
              <children>
          <callsbackend translate="title">
            <title>Backend Page Title</title>
          </callsbackend>
              </children>
            </calls>
          </children>
        </admin>
      </resources>
    </acl>
    <layout>
      <updates>
        <calls>
          <file>calls.xml</file>
        </calls>
      </updates>
    </layout>
  </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Comment: i replaced this file with config.xml, but its not working

Comment: Please confirm if this file available? `app/etc/modules/Bms_Calls.xml`

Comment: Also, it is very small thing but, did you flush cache after these changes?

Comment: yes, Bms_Calls.xml  file is there, and also i cleared the cache,